# Taking Unique Records From Two Tables

Tags: sql, yii, phpmyadmin

i am stuck at a silly problem. And it has to be one of the most cliche solution.

**Table** student_selection:

```
Columns
=======
student_id
subject_id
faculty_id
```

**Another table**: sub_group

```
Columns
=======
subject_id
sub_group
```

They are Joint on subject_id.

I want to find those subject_id from table sub_group where, the subject_id is not present in the student_selection table.

Eg:

```
sub_group(subject_id)
2
3
4

student_selection(subject_id)
2
3
2
3
2
3
```

**Output**

```
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a simple `not in` query to get the data.

Like:

```
SELECT 
    subject_id
FROM 
    sub_group
WHERE
    subject_id not in (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT subject_id 
        FROM
            student_selection
    )
```

Comment: Thankyou. i tried this: SELECT t.subject_id FROM `ssa_sub_group` `t` LEFT JOIN ssa_student_selection p ON p.subject_id = t.subject_id WHERE t.subject_id NOT IN p.subject_id :Why is it wrong?

Comment: Ok. I get it. I dont have to join. Thankyou.

Comment: Thankyou for editing. I shall keep in mind the next time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653561/custom-filters-in-tbgridview-yii-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL IN clause:

```
select subject_id from sub_group
where subject_id not in (select subject_id from student_selection);
```

Standard SQL EXISTS clause:

```
select subject_id from sub_group sg
where not exists 
  (select * from student_selection ss where ss.subject_id = sg.subject_id);
```

Set based query. Some dbms support set based operations. They use the word EXCEPT or MINUS to subtract one set from another. (MySQL doesn't support this.)

```
select subject_id from sub_group
except
select subject_id from student_selection;
```

At last you can use a trick where you outer join the second table and only stay with those results where there was a record outer-joined (i.e. there is no macthing record in the second table). This is also standard SQL. It is less readable for the unexperienced reader but happens to be faster on some dbms.

```
select sg.subject_id 
from sub_group sg
left join student_selection ss on ss.subject_id = sg.subject_id
where ss.subject_id is null;
```